# OpenVPN is connected but not worked on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: 18.04, vpn, openvpn

I think OpenVPN stopped working after Ubuntu update but I'm not sure.
If I use GUI, my VPN icon is upper-right corner is connected but I can't connect to my company website. In

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager.service
```

I have that in logs.

[image]

When I try connect to VPN by terminal using `sudo openvpn --config YOUR_SELECTED_CONNETION_TYPE.ovpn`

I have:

[image]

My firewall:

[image]

On my second system Windows 10, all work fine.

Do you have any idea what can I check or do you have any alternative how can I connect to vpn on ubuntu?

@edit

After some time I saw in journalclt log but I don't understand why is there TCP, because I using UDP to connect to this VPN and why that's not work on Ubuntu but on Windows don't have any problem...
[image]

Comment: check your client.ovpn file. Instead of tcp there should be udp protocol specified.

Comment: Hello. I have udp in my ovpn file. My file below:
`client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 193.222.135.193 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
ca /home/paulakarolina/Dokumenty/cert/ca.crt
cert /home/paulakarolina/Dokumenty/cert/PaulaJakubasik.crt
key /home/paulakarolina/Dokumenty/cert/PaulaJakubasik.key
verb 3`

Comment: What does say your openvpn log on the server?

Comment: I don't have access to server, so I can't check that. On second computer with Windows it's work, but on Linux not ;/

Comment: What is the cipher in windows ovpn file?